# Send payroll email on a schedule

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Hi guys I'm looking for some assistance on setting up a workflow.

The basic goal: Send a payroll email to our payroll team (same email every two weeks) with total hours worked, hourly pay, and total pay based on the other two. As it stands now I have a custom list that has the employee information. The daily pay and hours are in their own calculated columns.

The "totals" option in the view isn't working (all it says is "sum= "). So I need to sum up the hours worked really and send that out in an email multiplying that times the employees hourly pay.

Comment: Timer job is the solution for your requirement.

Comment: as Bhaskar said, would a timer job be an option? Or are you stuck using just the SharePoint designer as your tagging seem to indicate?

Comment: I believe my boss would have to give me different permissions to use a timer job, I'm currently a power user